# Multiple Function calls with one ng-click attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can I execute few actions by using one `ng-click` attribute? For example:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="createUser(); isVisiblePopup = true" value="Create new user">
```

Also I tried to use arrow function:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="createUser(); () => { isVisiblePopup = true }" value="Create new user">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method `createUserHandler()` to handle the click event:

Html:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="createUserHandler()" value="Create new user">
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.createUserHandler= function() {
    $scope.isVisiblePopup = true;
    $scope.createUser(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call your subsequent instructions inside the main one:

```
createUser = function () {
    isVisiblePopup = true;
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you really insist, you can call multiple functions by separating them with a ;

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y1z29mqy/

Comment: Yes I know but I find more elegant way. `createUser` function is resposible for creating users not for displaying popup.

Comment: You should usually try to avoid putting logic in the html: logic belongs in the controller. Maybe createUser() is wrongly named?

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="button" ng-click="function () { functionCall1(); functionCall2(); etc } ..` could do the trick for what you need. or having an other named function that get called that does the same as above for readability

Answer (score 1):

The first version

```
<input type="button" ng-click="createUser(); isVisiblePopup = true" value="Create new user">
```

looks good. What is your actual problem? Maybe its not working for another reason.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a action `doAll` which calls all methods and sets all values you want in that one click.